# Update Command with stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I have an update query(stored procedure) which is working properly in SQL Server when I execute it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE updatestudenthws(@stdid nvarchar(50),@hwid int, @grade float)
AS
UPDATE Table_Exercise_Answer 
SET
ExAns_Grade = @grade
WHERE ExAns_Exercise = @hwid AND ExAns_Student = @stdid
```

but when I run the program it does not have any effect in my table and also I don't have any error.

```
     con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("updatestudenthws", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@hwid", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@stdid", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@grade", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@hwid"].Value = hwid;
        cmd.Parameters["@stdid"].Value = studentid;
        cmd.Parameters["@grade"].Value = grade;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
     con.Close();
```

What is my mistake?
How should I do this work?

Comment: Did you check that you are passing the requited hwid and stdid parameters? Myabe the stdid is longer than 50 chars?

Comment: Why you defined `@hwid` as an `int` in your sp but you add paraneter as `SqlDbType.VarChar`?

Comment: I would suspect from parameters in where clause, have you checked their values in debug?

Comment: does your hwid, studentid, grade has values??

Comment: what's the return value from cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();? if it should be 0 then nothing was updated because of the where condition

Comment: @Soner Gönül what should I define? I already have not used this.

Comment: try changing  cmd.Parameters.Add("@hwid", SqlDbType.Int); and  cmd.Parameters.Add("@grade", SqlDbType.Float);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `AddWithValue()`, so you don't have to provide the type, which allowed you to make the mistake of passing `varchar` to an `int` parameter.

```
 con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("updatestudenthws", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hwid", hwid);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stdid", studentid);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@grade", grade);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
 con.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your ADO.NET code defining the parameters for the stored procedure is wrong in that you don't define the parameters with their proper datatypes.

Your stored procedure defines:

- `@stdid nvarchar(50)`  --> but you define it as `varchar`
- `@hwid int`  --> but you define it as `varchar`
- `@grade float` --> but you define it as `varchar`

You need to change your code to this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("updatestudenthws", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@hwid", SqlDbType.Int);   // this needs to be SqlDbType.Int 
cmd.Parameters.Add("@stdid", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);  // this should be SqlDbType.NVarChar and specify its proper length
cmd.Parameters.Add("@grade", SqlDbType.Float);  // this needs to be SqlDbType.Float
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use **AddWithValue()**, don't you have to provide the type passing like varchar to an int parameter.

```
 con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("updatestudenthws", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hwid", hwid);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stdid", studentid);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@grade", grade);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
     con.Close();
```